# Testing WinPCAP with a Console Application

Tags: console-application, pcap

I want to check if I could successfully load the dll's for WinPCAP and want to do it by writing a simple C/C++ console application. However I do not have neither experience nor an idea about how to do it. What I know is according to its def file:

```
LIBRARY Packet32

EXPORTS
    PacketOpenAdapter
    PacketSendPacket
    PacketAllocatePacket
    PacketInitPacket
    PacketFreePacket
    PacketResetAdapter
    PacketReceivePacket
    PacketCloseAdapter
    PacketSetHwFilter
    PacketGetAdapterNames
    PacketRequest
    PacketSetBuff
    PacketSetBpf
    PacketGetNetType
    PacketSetReadTimeout
    PacketSetNumWrites
    PacketGetNetInfo
    PacketSetMinToCopy
    PacketSetMaxLookahead
    PacketCancelPacket
    PacketLoadDriver
    PacketUnloadDriver
```

I must be checking these things. But how? Could you please help me?

Best Regards

Comment: what do you mean by "test" ? check the integrity ? or check the functions ?

Comment: You need to include the WinPCAP header files (`.h`)in your application to compile against. Then you need to link against the import library (`.lib`). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762752/why-winpcap-requires-both-lib-and-dll-to-run

Comment: [The Internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=winpcap+example+code) is your friend, by the way.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I need to check integrity I guess? For example, I need to check if PacketSendPacket works successfully.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I have seen those codes but could not be sure about them. I feel like I need a console application that checks PacketOpenAdapter, PacketSendPacket, PacketAllocatePacket etc. if they are successfully loaded?

Comment: Then can you show the codes?

Comment: What do you mean "successfully loaded?" It's a DLL, you have two options: 1) Link your executable against an import library (`.lib`), and the loader will fix everything up for you. 2) You call `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` to do your own "late-binding", and call the functions via function pointers.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart First, I am sorry for the inconvenience caused by my ignorance. :/ What I want to do is basically like in this link: http://www.winpcap.org/pipermail/winpcap-users/2011-December/004549.html I want to write a code that uses PacketSetReadTimeout, PacketSetBuff etc. and see how they work.

Answer (score 0):

Those are functions in the packet32 library, not in the WinPcap library.  Packet32 is a library of routines that provide access to the lower-level packet capture mechanism that WinPcap uses, in a fashion that hides from WinPcap the differences between "Windows OT" (95, 98, Me) and Windows NT (modern versions of Windows, up to and including Windows 8); it's not intended to be used by users.  See [the page about packet32 in the WinPcap documentation](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__packetapi.html).

You *don't* need a console application that checks any of the packet32 routines.  What you need is a console application that checks the *WinPcap* routines; if packet32 isn't working, those routines won't work, either.  So you should look at some of the sample programs on the Internet for libpcap/WinPcap.

Comment: I am going to implement another driver depends on packet32.dll and only packet32.dll seems to be enough for me. I do not need wpcap.dll and hence do not want to install it. My current problem is that at at first system loads Packet32.dll but just after a few seconds it gets unloaded. Do you have an idea about it?